# Login baseado no dominio do email

Tags: segurança, email

Estou pensando em um sistema onde somente usuários que possuem email com domínio `empresa.com` poderão se cadastrar. Após o cadastro será enviado um email de validação do email.

Até ai tudo bem, consigo verificar facilmente qual é o domínio do email quando o usuário estiver se cadastrando.

Vamos supor também que a pessoa responsável por distribuir os emails do domínio `empresa.com` tem total controle de todos os emails ativos.

Agora a minha pergunta é, existe alguma falha de segurança que possa permitir que usuários com outros domínios se cadastrem, ou que mascarem o email deles?

Por exemplo, o email `invasor@empresa.com` não é um email real, mas o usuário consegue mascarar o email de modo que `invasor@empresa.com` seja redirecionado para `invasor@concorrente.com`?

Existe alguma possibilidade de que um envenenamento de DNS possa afetar a segurança desse sistema?

Veja bem que a pergunta não está relacionada a como implementar e sim quais são as possíveis falhas de seguranças ou ataques que eu posso sofrer, na tentativa de burlar a verificação do domínio do email.

Comment: Empresas como a JetBrains e a Microsoft fazem algo do tipo para validar quem é universitário, para seus programas de licença estudantil. Então, acho que tem como fazer funcionar, mas também vou ficar aguardando uma resposta.

Comment: Normalmente você vai mandar um email com um link de confirmação para a pessoa, certo? Basta no seu sistema você mandar para o domínio certo. Para alguém interceptar isso, somente bagunçando o SEU dns, e não o do usuário. Ou, acessando a conta do usuário, mas aí o problema é muito mais abrangente que o seu sistema.

Comment: @Bacco acho que poderia criar uma resposta, não?

Comment: @Math o duro é parar e elaborar todos os detalhes. Em parte o Sergio Cabral respondeu embaixo, apesar de eu achar que falta um pouco de profundidade no contexto.

Comment: Rubico!!! Eu... eu... eu... rsrsrsrs Vê se ajudou a resposta.

Comment: Sim, a resposta do Sergio está "correta". Não vejo nada errada com ela e assim como o Bacco disse, poderia ser mais profunda. Se ninguém possuir uma resposta melhor aceitarei ela. Mas o que eu estou querendo mesmo é algo mais ***fora da caixa***. Tipo o envenenamento de DNS. Algo que fuja do caminho perfeito onde ninguém está realmente se esforçando para entrar.

Comment: Sim tem como fazer isso, eu uso redirecionamento bastante, porque não usa cPanel? é util para fazer isso de email, se não tem cPanel e tem usar registro.br muito trampo configurar MX + Redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer validar em primeiro plano não é o usuário do e-mail, sim o próprio domínio.

Se o DNS primário estiver comprometido tudo é possível, por isso que essas validações são concretizadas através de registros TXT, sendo possível verificar que o proprietário validou.

Outro ponto é trabalhar com empresas que utilizem SSL com certificação de terceiros, assim a maiorias das aplicações por padrão vão falhar na verificação caso algum host tente impersonar através de ataques de DNS ou comprometimento dos servidores de DNS primários.

Veja como o Google Apps exige o campo TXT:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=pt-BR

Vale também ler mais sobre medidas de segurança de e-mail mais recentes (spf, dkim, dmarc):

http://www.rsdezoito.com.br/blog/spf-dkim-e-dmarc-e-mail-marketing-seguro/

Comment: Por enquanto, pela citação de SPF, DKIM e DMARC foi a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade não existe uma forma segura de garantir que o email pertença mesmo a empresa. A falha sempre vai estar do lado da empresa, pois se uma pessoa que possui acesso ao DNS fornecer informações a terceiros, ou a senha de acesso ao DNS cair em mãos erradas não há nada que vc possa fazer para garantir a integridade de quem está acessando.

Assim como se vc tivesse um acesso por login e senha normal e a senha cair em mãos erradas não há muito o que fazer.

O que vc pode fazer é dificultar o acesso de possíveis falhas de segurança.

1. Mapear pela localidade onde é feito a maioria dos acessos de determinado usuário, e assim que for acessado de uma localidade diferente gerar e-mails de confirmação ou aviso aos responsáveis.
2. Para determinadas empresas que tem IP fixo vc pode validar acessos apenas daqueles IP's cadastrados para aquela empresa/usuário.

No mais não há muito o que seja feito, a falha sempre estará do lado do usuário/empresa, sites grandes como google, amazon e outros tambem tem problemas em garantir a integridade ou autenticidade de quem está acessando.

Answer (score 1):

Se o domínio `empresa.com` pertence a empresa dona do software **é seguro**.
Na verdade a segurança depende de quem é dona do domínio.

Por exemplo, eu tenho meu domínio `splitz.com.br`, se alguém tentar se cadastrar em algum serviço (Google, Microsoft, etc.) usando meu domínio como `invasor@splitz.com.br` um e-mail de confirmação vai ser enviado para `invasor@splitz.com.br`, mas como eu sou o dono do domínio sou eu que recebo o e-mail, não o invasor. **Resultado: ele não terá seu e-mail confirmado e sua conta não será ativada no serviço**

Aconteceu comigo... Tentaram se registrar no Facebook usando meu e-mail `sergio@cabral.br.com`, o resultado é que eu recebi o e-mail de confirmação, confirmei a conta, entrei no Facebook da pessoal (invasor?), mudei a senha dela, e exclui essa minha conta recem criada no Facebook.

Finalizando... quem é dona do domínio faz o que quiser. O invasor teria de ter acesso ao DNS do domínio para causar problemas. Digo ter a senha de acesso ao site Regitro.Br (ou GoDaddy, CentralNic, etc) para modificar as entradas DNS abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Somente tendo acesso a esta tela o invasor poderia, como você disse mascarar o email de modo que invasor@empresa.com seja redirecionado para invasor@concorrente.com?

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar responder as duas coisas que você pediu (ou o que eu entendi na pergunta):

Para verificar automaticamente se o email pertence à empresa que quer restringir use o seguinte código:

> $verifica = explode('@',$email);
>
> $dominio = $verifica[1];
>
> if($dominio == 'empresa.com.br'){  return true; }

Agora vamos conversar sobre segurança em emails:
Realmente é seguro, e muito difícil uma pessoa burlar o RECEBIMENTO de um e-mail escolhendo um domínio.
Para alguém burlar o ENVIO de um e-mail usava-se um código muito fácil, que não sei se hoje em dia já foi corrigido. No cabeçalho do email, alguns soft permitem alterar o cabeçalho quando enviar (já fiz isso :). Simplesmente altera onde fica a propriedade from: fulano@grandeempresa.com.br. Isto apenas par envio, mas se você enviar um email para aquele email, iso vai ficar parado no SERVIDOR IMAP, que possivelmente não vai encontrar nada.

Ou seja, a pessoa envia emails falsos mas não recebe naquele email falso.

Então esta proposta é SEGURA ;)

-- Só lembrando que o início do Facebook foi assim, restrito para quem tivesse emails @edu.com (ou seja apenas estudantes universitários).

Comment: Se alguem quebrar a segurança das zonas MX Dns poderá fazer muito mais do que conectar com um email falso.

Comment: A questão em si nem é de código, mas de analise de segurança, eu acredito que sempre haverá uma falha. Em casos de mentes superiores nessa área é possível utilizar até mesmo um ALIAS.

Comment: Claro que não, todas essas configurações, Entradas MX, Dns, Alias, são apenas de controle do operador do Sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Se o "invasor" tiver acesso aos emails desta empresa, e criar um redirecionamento, ele poderá burlar isso sem problemas.

Partindo do principio que trata-se de uma empresa com domínio próprio, seguem algumas ideias:

1. Checagem de SPF

Você pode fazer verificações pelos registros de SPF e DNS para o domínio. Checando o SPF do domínio, você consegue obter os IPs dos MX da empresa. Você pode

algoritmo:
dns_get_record ("dominio.com", DNS_TXT);
localize os registros com v=spf1
localize nesta linha todos os IPs e ponha em um array
por exemplo se no MX constar: 200.10.20.30
restrinja os cadastros para a rede 200.10.20.__

2. Checagem de Whois

Pode obter os IPs do domínio da empresa, e verificar o IP de quem está acessando. Fazendo um WHOIS no IP de quem está acessando lhe confirmará quem é o dono do IP, se a empresa usar IP fixo. Você pode restringir acessos de provedores de banda larga como GVT, OI, etc.. Ou então simplesmente não fazer a consulta nestes casos.

algoritmo:
gethostbyname ("dominio.com")
aplica um whois no domínio 
filtra pelo nome da organização

3. Mapear o histórico de IPs

Você pode simplesmente fazer um banco de dados com o histórico de IPs usados por cada domínio (usuários com emails @dominio.com) ao acessar o sistema. Assim pode ver se estão na mesma rede sempre. Caso algum acesso "fuja" ao padrão de rede, pode bloquear o usuário especificamente.

Por exemplo:

usuario1@empresa.com - IP 200.10.20.30 
usuario2@empresa.com - IP 200.10.20.32
usuario3@empresa.com - IP 200.10.20.37

Pode usar um pattern de frequencia para "200.10.20".

invasor@empresa.com - IP 177.81.10.20 - Bloquear (IP totalmente diferente)